# Can one use multiple destiny points to activate multiple talents in one action?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

Specifically, I will be asking about these two talents:

> Anatomy Lessons:
> On a successful attack during combat with a non-starship/vehicle weapon, the character may spend one Destiny Point to add damage equal to his Intelligence to one hit of the successful attack.
>
> Targeted Blow:
> On a successful attack during combat with a non-starship/vehicle weapon, the character may spend one Destiny Point to add damage equal to his Agility to one hit of the successful attack.

Given that I have two Destiny Points available, and have made a successful attack during combat, could I spend both Destiny Points to activate each talent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, you cannot.

Page 27 states that

> A player can only spend one light side Destiny Point during a single action…

It's under the **How Destiny Points are Used** header, second paragraph.

Comment: It should be noted that there are exceptions to this limit, but not the intention of the limit. Some Talents and Signature Abilities call for the expenditure of multiple Destiny Points to activate. The use of Destiny Points for a single purpose is still maintained. It may be clearer to think of it as being only permitted to apply Destiny Points to one use per Turn, with a usual cap of 1 point unless otherwise specified.