# Can several players use several Destiny Points in a single action?

Tags: star-wars-force-and-destiny

Can several players use several Destiny Points in a single action, one Destiny Point per player?

Comment: Related: [Can one use multiple destiny points to activate multiple talents in one action?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70564/can-one-use-multiple-destiny-points-to-activate-multiple-talents-in-one-action)

Answer (score 1):

### One destiny point per round.

And you could argue that only the player performing the action (and the GM) can use Destiny Points.

It's under the sub heading "The Limits of Luck" Force and Destiny p.37, Age of Rebellion p.36 and Edge of the Empire p.2 :

> Conversion takes place at the end of the action during which the Destiny Point was used, preventing players or CMs from immediately spending a just-converted Destiny Point.

And also tells us the limitation of use:

> Destiny is a powerful resource, but it is limited. A player can **only spend one light side Destiny Point during a single action**
>
> The CM likewise is limited to spending one dark side point per action.

As for who can use the Destiny Points:

> **The active player** (the player or GM forming the dice pool) always has the first chance to use a Destiny Point.

Which follows with:

> Once he has decided whether or not he will use a Destiny Point, the **other party** involved in the check (the targeted player, or the GM in the case of an NPC) has the opportunity to **respond and spend a Destiny Point** as well.

In other words:

## No other player can spend Destiny Points.